# Location of the function mosMainBody() in Joomla 1.8

Tags: php, joomla

I am looking for a function that is titled **mosMainBody**() in Joomla. Is there a specific folder where it is located? Thanks in advance

Comment: @nibra is right. Please don't waste time on such an old CMS version that isn't supported anymore. Start migrating to Joomla 3.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There was never a Joomla! version 1.8.
2. The function name tells me, that you're looking at Joomla! 1.0 (apparently 1.0.8), which had its End of Life in 2009. Don't waste your time on such old stuff, it will never pay off.
3. `mosMainBody()` was located in `includes/frontend.php`.

Comment: thanks and I know its old I just cant upgrade it due to company orders just fixing what they want to fix